# Spring mvc Test Webapplication vs StandAlone

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, controller, mockito

I'm doing a junit test for my spring mvc web application.
    I'm using mockito to simulate the request and response,the problem is when i Auto-wired the webApplicationContext and i set a breakpoint on the method , the execution stopped as it supposed to do
      and everything works fine but when i use a standaloneSetup with an instance of the class ,the execution doesn't stop at breakpoint (on the controller method) even if i got an ok status and always with an empty response,
    is it normal?
Thanks.

this is the code, it's simple:

```
  public class EmployeeTest{
 private MockMvc mockMvc; 
 @Mock EmployeeController employerctrl;
 @Before public void setUp() { MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employerctrl).build();} 
 @Test
           public void LoginTest() throws Exception {
             this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/login"))  
             .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())  
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("login-page"));

            }
 }
```

and this is the class :

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 @Controller
 public class EmployeeController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/login")
 public String login() {
    return "login-page";
    }
 }
```

i have always an OK status but , without stopping in breakpoint and an empty body response.

Comment: because your mocked that class?

Comment: Yes , i'm doing this:
 private MockMvc mockMvc; 
 @Mock 
 EmployeeController employerctrl;
 Before
   public void setUp() {
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employerctrl).build();}   .It sould be like this?

Comment: show us some code what you are doing?

Comment: You must not mock the controller.

Comment: thanks, it works with a simple instance of the class.